# Elasticsearch doesn't return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a strange issue in elasticsearch query. I don't know much about elasticsearch. My query is:

```
    {
      "query":
      {
        "bool":
        {
          "must":
            [
              {
                 "text":
                 {
                   "countryCode2":"DE"
                 }
              }
            ],
          "must_not":[],
          "should":[]
        }
    },"from":0,"size":1,"sort":[],"facets":{}
  }
```

The issues is for "DE". It is giving me results but for "BE" or "IN" it returns empty result.

Comment: are you sure you have data corresponding to "BE" and "IN"?

Comment: yes. Because when I get all countries list, I get BE and IN records

Comment: I think it may be a plot against indians and belgians by the germans.

Comment: :D well, BE and IN are just examples. It doesn't return results for some other countries, too.

Comment: What is your mapping? Is your countryCode2 field analyzed or not analyzed?

Comment: it is analyzed and I have also tried it with "not_analyzed" but it is not working either. And I found something, elastic is not generating token for some entries. I don't know why? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indexing using the default mapping, which by default removes english stopwords. The country codes "IN", "BE", and many more are stopwords which don't even get indexed, therefore it's not possible to have matching documents, nor get back those country codes when faceting on that field.

The solution is to reindex after having submitted your own mapping for the country code field:

```
{
    "your_type_name" : {
        "country" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

If you already tried to do this but nothing changed, the mapping didn't get submitted properly. I would suggest to double check that its json structure is correct and that you can actually get it back using the get mapping api.

As this is a common problem the defaults are probably going to change in the future to be less intrusive and avoid applying any language dependent text analysis.

Comment: Thank you..! I did not know about stopwords. Thanks for explanation.